# how to replace null (number) to 'unknown' (char) in SQL?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, case, sql-null

How to replace all null values in Grade1 to 'Unknown' in SQL?
This didn't work because Grade1 is number but 'Unknown' is char.

```
SELECT NVL(Grade1, 'Unknown')
FROM table;
```

[table]

```
Student   Grade1  Grade2
1          NULL     0.88
2          0.80     0.50
3          NULL     0.40
```

Comment: Since you're using `nvl`, I assume that you're using Oracle rather than some other relational database.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do just what you want. Both branches of `NVL()`  must return the same datatype. If you  really want "Unknown" for `NULL`  values, then you have to convert non-`NULL`  values to strings as well.

Assuming that you are running Oracle, as `NVL()` suggests:

```
NVL(TO_CHAR(grade1), 'Unknown')
```

That said, I would rather keep `NULL` values as they are. This seems like the right way to represent the absence of data (`NULL` really stands for "Unknown").

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your intention is to have the `Grade1` column in the result be a `varchar2`

```
coalesce( to_char( Grade1 ), 'Unknown' )
```

You could use `nvl` rather than `coalesce` but `coalese` is more flexible (it can take more than two parameters) and more portable across different databases.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT DECODE(Grade1, null, 'UnKnown', Grade1) FROM tbl;
```